# Cisco Packet Tracer: Closing a Telnet session manually

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

How do I escape a Telnet session in Cisco's `Packet Tracer 6.1.1`, when I'm connected from an end-device such as *PC-PT* or *Laptop-PT* to a *Server-PT* device? For instance, `telnet 192.168.0.1 80`. I'm using the program on a Windows PC. How do I abort that simulated Telnet session?

Does not work:

- <kbd>^</kbd>
- <kbd>^</kbd> <kbd>]</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>^</kbd> <kbd>]</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>6</kbd> for <kbd>^</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>6</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd>

Comment: have you tried Ctrl + Z?

Comment: Did not work either.

Comment: Tried all of the above with Packet Tracer `6.2.0.0052`. No success.

Answer (score 1):

In the mostly Cisco IOS the **default** way to break a telnet command is:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd> and then <kbd>X</kbd>.

Packet Tracer is a **Simulation Tool** to practice and learn in some netacad courses as **CCNA** and there are a tons of unsupported features and bugs in all packet tracer versions and as the mostly closed sourced programs there are not an open bug tracker or changelog to check.

**My suggestion.**

If you want to success in your personal test you should use [GNS3](http://www.gns3.com/) and sandboxes(vms).

But if you want to **success** your netacad courses just folow the instruccions step by step without "explore" because Packet Tracer is tested to work with the provided courses assesments and test.

Good luck and do not give up.

Comment: This combination is already in the list. Unfortunately, it does not work. Still, thank you for effort!

Comment: @user2964971 i saw it was on the list, just i wanted to left in clear because is not too much mistery, personally is more chance to be a bug than a diferent key combination, i mean 99% bug vs 1% combination

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> then x should work

Comment: Did not work either. Equals <kbd>^</kbd> on a typical US keyboard.